# asp.net vb socket works on first iteration only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a server used to get info from SAPGUI. Everything works fine for a first request but nothing after that. The first iteration waits for a socket event. Once the socket is read for the first time it just loops without reading the receive buffer.  I am assuming I need to reset the listener but am having trouble doing so.

'first iteration it works as expected but readbyte is always 0 after that even though it loops through fine.
'what I don't get is that the first iteration it waits for data to come down the socket, but after that it just loops
'and doesn't retreive anything.

```vb
Dim listenerSocket As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

Dim ipend As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888)

listenerSocket.Bind(ipend)
listenerSocket.Listen(0)

Dim clientSocket As Socket = listenerSocket.Accept()
Dim Buffer As Byte() = New Byte(clientSocket.SendBufferSize - 1) {}
Dim readByte, sendByte As Integer
Dim Sbuffer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some form of SAP response!")
Dim clientError As System.Net.Sockets.SocketError

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection : ")
   
For infinitecounter = 1 To 3
    infinitecounter = 1
    readByte = clientSocket.Receive(Buffer) 

    While (True)
        If readByte > 0 Then
            Dim rData As Byte() = New Byte(readByte - 1) {}
            Array.Copy(Buffer, rData, readByte)

            SAPrq = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rData)
            SAPpar = Left(SAPrq, 1)

            SAPpar1 = InStr(SAPrq, "%")

            If SAPpar = 1 Then
                SAPnwk = Mid(SAPrq, 3)

                xy = Getbam(SAPnwk)' this is a function that talks to SAP and it works on first loop
            End If
End if
        End While
           
    Next
```

I tried adding setting infinitecounter = 2 before the next statement and adding an if statement to reset the listener but failed.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the code formatting so that it's more readable.  You're missing an `End If` somewhere, can you fix that?

Comment: I am open to an alternative Socket but since I'm not used to VB.net , I'd need some help with coding that!

Thanks

Pete

Comment: I was thinking of using non blocking Sockets  or Async mode but have no clue as to how to implement it! 

Thanks